# Using a regex to find the word from content

Tags: php, regex

My text is as below:

```
9/91 a1 2a cx.papaya 94000
9/92 b2 3a x44b mango 10220
9/93 3 3a x333 pineapple
9/94 x4 cx.apple 94000
9/95 5 55 cyz cx.orange
```

I try to develop a regex to find out the word as below table but it's not working.

My regex is `^[0-9\/]+.*\s(.*)\s(\d{5})$`.

This is my expectation:

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/91 a1 2a | papaya | 94000 |
| 9/92 b2 3a x44b | mango | 10220 |
| 9/93 3 3a x333 | pineapple |  |
| 9/94 x4 | apple | 94000 |
| 9/95 5 55 cyz | orange |  |

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the failing regular expressions as well as their outcome? That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: why orange is x6? what is the logic behind it? and the fruit column that is prefixed with cx.orange is it always like this or can it be 2 dots or a different prefix? and will the fruit always be in the last place after the last dot?

Comment: @pr1nc3 Sorry, It's my mistake, I have updated.

Comment: Perhaps like this `^(\d+/\d+\h.*?)[\h.](\p{L}+)(?:\h(\d{5}))?$` https://regex101.com/r/MZ6Zye/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird You're my hero. Thank you so much. Your answer is correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

```
^(\d+\/\d+\hx\d+)\h(?:\w+\.)?(\w+)\h?(\d+)?$
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xWrNga/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^`: start anchor
- `(\d+\/\d+\hx\d+)`: first capturing group, match pattern `9/91 x1` (one or many digits `\d+`, a slash with escape character `\/`, one or many digits `\d+`, a space `\h`, character `x`, one or many digits `\d+`)
- `\h(?:\w+\.)?`: a space `\h` followed by a non capturing group that match optional pattern `cx.`
- `(\w+)`: second capturing group, match any words characters `\w+` one or many times
- `\h?(\d+)?` third capturing group (which is optional), a optional space `\h?`, optional capturing group `(\d+)?`
- `$`: end anchor

---

**Update:** OP changed their question so this is my new attempt:

Thanks @The fourth bird for remove trailing space in the third capturing group

```
^(\d+\/\d+(?:\h\w+)+)\h(?:\w+\.)?([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\h(\d+))?$
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/e84Qzi/4)

- I added `(?:\h\w+)+` to the first capturing group to match multiple characters group like  `a1 2a` after `9/91` pattern
- I changed the second capturing group from `\w+` to `[a-zA-Z]+` to match only word character.

Comment: If you don't want to allow a trailing space if there is no number at the end `(^\d+\/\d+\hx\d+)\h(?:\w+\.)?(\w+)(?:\h(\d+))?$`

Comment: Sorry my question is not correctly, I have updated it.

Comment: @JCChanChanJC I updated my answer, please take a look if it helps

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to create a group for the first part and to account for the `x` sequence. You should also make the last part optional and account for the leading optional prefix in your second part. The result of those changes could look like this:

```
^([0-9\/]+ x\d) (?:\w+\.)?(\w+)(?: (\d{5}))?$
```

You can add the lazy group `(?: \w+)+?` to reflect the additional trailing sequence to the first group in your changed question:

```
^([0-9\/]+(?: \w+)+?) (?:\w+\.)?(\w+)(?: (\d{5}))?$
```

Comment: Sorry my question is not correctly, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged also php I will provide a PHP solution without a regex for your problem so you can also check it out as an alternative.

```
   <?php
$input = '9/93 3 3a x333 pineapple';

$splitter = explode(' ',$input);

$maxArrayPositions = array_key_last($splitter);

$group3 = '';
$group1 = '';
if(is_numeric(end($splitter))){
    $group3 = end($splitter);
    $fruit = explode('.',$splitter[$maxArrayPositions-1]);
    $group2 = end($fruit);
    $counter = 0;
    while($counter < $maxArrayPositions -1){
        $group1 = $group1. ' ' .$splitter[$counter];
        $counter ++;
    }
}
else{
    $fruit = explode('.',end($splitter));
    $group2 = end($fruit);
    $counter = 0;
    while($counter < $maxArrayPositions){
        $group1 = $group1. ' ' .$splitter[$counter];
        $counter ++;
    }
}

    
echo 'group 1 is '. $group1. "\n";
echo 'group 2 is '. $group2. "\n";
echo 'group 3 is '. $group3. "\n";
```

The output of the `group` variables is as expected.

Basically your strings have a pattern.

- the last column is optional and can be a number or empty
- the before-last column is your fruit with or without a prefix but you only want the part after the last dot
- everything before the semi-last column is your concatenated string.

(updated my answer based on your latest input change in your question).

Answer (score -1):

Probably something like this might help:

```
(\d\/\d+\s.\d).+(papaya) ?(\d+)?
```

you can try to play around with regexp on some sites like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you so much but I just change papaya to others. Sorry for lately reply.